# MariaDB : How to SUM child values from a GROUPED parent

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have found a tricky problem today.

I have an SQL query which collects a set of data from a number of different tables. It is a single query run on the "parent" table and outputs about 40 blocks of data. Some of these blocks are derived values such as "SUM"s.

This works perfectly, except on a page which listed results searched by the user. This page has an identical query with another table, which lists alias names for the "name" of the parent tables row.

When I add this JOIN to the SQL, the derived values are incorrect, being +1 more than they should be (double). The join is set on a PK just the same as every other reference table on the SQL,

The alias is linked to the main SQL by:

```
LEFT JOIN ealias eza ON Nee.see_id = eza.ee_id
```

Here is the corresponding alias list:

First: the Alias table:

**ealias**

```
  id          name                 reference    
----------------------------------------------
 528    St Patrick's Academy        12077
 121    St. Patrick's High School   12077
```

I would expect the LEFT JOIN to only attach zero or one of these (I am unfamiliar with MySQL/MariaDB joining multiple right instances on a LEFT JOIN), to be defined by the search term "name", but it appears to be joining both of these which is making the SUM value from another child table incorrect.

Here is the raw data row that is being summed incorrectly:

**BOBJee**

```
 id     periodenddate    ee_id    bame    applicants    intake      
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
 80350   2012-03-31      12077     2          1           1
```

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT Nee.see_id, 
       Nee.ename as EE_Name, 
       ... lots of columns removed ...
       IFNULL(SUM(BJ.`applicants`), '--') as sum_applicants,
       IFNULL(SUM(BJ.`intake`), '--') as sum_intakes,
       (FLOOR(SUM(BJ.`intake`) / SUM(BJ.`applicants`) * 100)) as conversion, 
FROM new_EEs Nee 
       ... Lots if LEFT JOINS to other tables removed ...
    LEFT JOIN BOBJee BJ    ON Nee.see_id = BJ.ee_id 
    LEFT JOIN ealias eza   ON Nee.see_id = eza.ee_id 
WHERE Nee.deleted IS NULL AND (Nee.ename LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchVar,'%') 
      OR eza.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchVar ,'%')
      OR CONCAT_WS(', ',Nee.address, Nee.town, Nee.postcode) LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchVar ,'%')) 
GROUP BY Nee.see_id
```

**Output from this SQL:**

> 12077 | St. Patrick's Academy | ... | 2 | 2 | 100

The figures 2 here should be 1's!

If I remove the ealias column reference, all parts of the SQL work correctly. However, with the ealias table LEFT JOIN in place (nessecary for the search feature), the SUM values, from the `BOBJee` table are being summed apparently for each ealias before being grouped by the `see_id` (the PK of the main table), I hypothesis this is because the eealias LEFT JOIN is somehow causing the GROUP BY to combine the values of the SUM, rather than to collect all the data on a per-see_id basis.

Because the `name` search is in an `OR` (NEE.name *or* ealias.name) I'm not cleaar how to move this `WHERE` criteria into the JOIN criteria so that only one alias is joined.

All the values in the SELECT cause should be grouped by the see_id (the PK of the main table), SUMS within this should not be grouped

- 5.5.68-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

What I'm Looking for:

- People search a text term which may appear in a list of aliases of any see_id.
- The results of this are GROUPED BY the PK of the parent table,
- SUM values (or any values from any other table) should not be duplicated due to numerous aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## My Solution

My solution was to duplicate the `eza.name LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')` on the end of the `LEFT JOIN eealias eza ON Nee.see_id = eza.ee_id` so:

```
LEFT JOIN ealias eza ON Nee.see_id = eza.ee_id AND eza.name LIKE CONCAT('%', :searchVar ,'%')
```

However this adds another duplicate variable to insert into the SQL and,er, is a duplicate so I'm sure this isn't the best approach.